# Apache virtual host allow download of jar file

Tags: jar, apache2, virtualhost

I just made a Virtual host using latest apache in ubuntu.

It finds my index.html and serves it correctly, however when trying to download myfile.jar (also in /var/www) from a remote host it returns 404. Doing this locally works fine...

After lots of googling a mime type was added with the addtype directive however this has not solved the problem for remote hosts.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason why a jar file should not be delivered. It might be served imperfectly if the MIME type is incorrect, but it shouldn't produce a 404.

- Check whether the JAR file has permissions that allow Apache to access it
- Check out `error.log` to see the jar's exact path that Apache failed to find. That will also tell you whether you're maybe operating in the wrong directory.